# Git: Is there a short way to setup a new branch to track a remote branch?

Tags: git, branch, tracking

The usual command is:

```
git checkout origin/branch_i_want -b branch_i_want
```

Git responds with:

```
Branch branch_i_want setup to track remote branch branch_i_want from origin.
```

This is fine.

My question is simple. Most of the time, the locally created branch has the same name as the remote branch. Is there a git command that does this so I do not need to type the branch name twice?

In other words, is there something like:

git checkout --autocreate-tracking origin/branch_i_want

Which would, in theory create a local branch named branch_i_want and set it up to track origin/branch_i_want ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With recent git (I think >= 1.7) you can just do `git checkout -t remotename/branchname`, and `-b branchame` is implied.